# Why are user groups not updating when logging out and in again?

Tags: arch-linux, group

I've just installed Arch Linux, and configured a user to be a member of the "network" group. `newgrp network` works, but after logging out of GNOME and back in again I still just have the old groups:

```
$ groups
wheel username
```

Do I really have to reboot (or maybe restart gdm) to have this new group apply?

---

After logging out and in again a *second* time I now have the new group. Is this a known issue, maybe only appearing the very first time I run GNOME?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045993/after-adding-a-group-logoutlogin-is-not-enough-in-18-04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1045993/10371), on recent GNOME versions you have to either reboot or do this:

1. Log out
2. Go to a virtual terminal
3. Log in
4. `loginctl terminate-user "$USER"`
5. Press Win + F1 to return to the login form (Tried on Ubuntu)

Comment: Works for Manjaro with Cinnamon 5.2.7. I was really wondering what was happening, thanks for the tip!